# How to download Minecraft for Linux without an internet connection on that linux computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have 2 computers.  One is an old Windows machine.  The other is a modern Linux machine.

I want to play Minecraft on my Linux machine.

Unfortunately, the Linux machine does not have any way of connecting to the Internet.

When I go to minecraft.net, and login, and click [download], and click [show all platforms] I see a list of launchers for Minecraft.  But I need more than the launcher.  I need the launcher and all the MC files.

**How can I download Minecraft using one operating system and transfer those files to a different OS?**

(I'm only asking about the minecraft stuff, such as valid file locations, here. Mounting discs or linux commands are not part of this question!)

Comment: just copy the `%appdata%\.minecraft` (windows) to `~/.mincraft`, however you are going to run into trouble with the login which requires the internet

Comment: I would try to get a pair of cheap network cards and connect both computers with each other, you can share the internet connection of the windows PC with the Linux one.

Comment: David - you can't download a complete Linux version of Minecraft.  So you need to know what bits to copy from the Windows install.  Notice that the accepted answer mentions 'flash drives' as part of its answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Download the .jar version of Minecraft from the website
- Force update Minecraft on your Windows Machine and login
- Press `Ctrl+r` and type `%appdata%` and copy your .minecraft folder
- Put it on a USB and insert the USB into your Linux Machine
- Copy the `.minecraft` folder to `~/.minecraft` in your Linux machine
- Login as usual and click `"Play Offline"`

You will have the following Issues:

1. Generally Linux doesn't have java per-installed and you will need Internet connection
2. You cannot play online

You should just get a Ethernet cable and tether internet off of your windows machine. Or do as uncovery said and get cheap network cards connect them.

Comment: Have you actually done this or are you just guessing? Doing this from Win to Mac gives a blackscreen crash caused by the natives folder containing the wrong platform-specific files. Don't you get the same from Win to Linux?

Comment: I have actually done this using Ubuntu, and it seemed to work fine. I never like using Macs, but they are UNIX based, so it should still work? On the minecraft website, there are different instructions given to Mac users, although I'd just say that that is to get it recognised as an application.

Comment: Yes, it may interfere due to platform specific natives, you may have to grab the LWJGL for linux from their Site and move it to the /natives folder.